# Drupal Views Non-admin user permissions

Tags: views

I have a view that seeks to find users that have not filled in a form on the site which is a personal profile. It works correctly for admin user, but not for other user roles although the permissions have been set to allow this.

The view is a view of users and uses a relationship to their authored content.

The full view code is:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'mentees_without_profiles_';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'Mentees without profiles ';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Mentees without profiles ';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  3 => '3',
  6 => '6',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Relationship: User: Content authored */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'User Name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: User: E-mail */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: User: E-mail */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['mail']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
/* Filter criterion: User: Active */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: User: Roles */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['id'] = 'rid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['table'] = 'users_roles';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['field'] = 'rid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['value'] = array(
  4 => '4',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['operator'] = 'empty';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'mentees-without-profiles';
$translatables['mentees_without_profiles_'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Mentees without profiles '),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('nodes'),
  t('User Name'),
  t('E-mail'),
  t('Page'),
);
```

Comment: where did you set the `permission` for your `view` ?

Answer (score 2):

Check whether those users have the permission to view other user profile.

I am posting this as an answer instead of comment because I don't have enough reputation to add comment, so don't down vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set the permission for view correctly, the problem won't be solved. There is a problem with the that relationship: "User: Content authored". Only admin can view the results. Issue submitted [here](http://drupal.org/node/1838796)

One solution recommended is to use [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) to create a view (name it form_values_view for example) that get the form values required then add a views field inside your view `mentees_without_profiles_` that read the values of view `form_values_view`.

you can also use module [Views PHP filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) and write your own handler

Another solution is to use Views Api to add your custom filter handler or use hook_views_query_alter() and join your form tables then filter the view result